# Error CRRTC8550E when loading new repository workspace to sandbox

Tags: windows, visual-studio, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

Using Rational Team Concert (aka Jazz source control), when loading a new repository workspace to a sandbox I am encountering error CRRTC8550E, and the resulting sandbox is incomplete. I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 19 and the RTC plug-in for Visual Studio (6.0.6.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when the repository contains symbolic links and RTC does not have sufficient permission to create the required links on the local Windows file system. The simple workaround for this is to run Visual Studio as administrator.